# Numeric or value error: character string buffer too small

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, ora-06502

I am having trouble with this simple query in oracle application express and am getting this error:

> Query cannot be parsed, please check the syntax of your query.
>   (ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer
>   too small)"

```
SELECT E.EQUIPMENTID, E.EQUIPMENTDESCRIPTION
From EQUIPMENT as E
left outer join EQUIPMENT_CHECKOUT as EC 
on E.EQUIPMENTID = EC.EQUIPMENTID
WHERE EC.EQUIPMENTID is null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error might be misleading in this case. You don't include `AS` when specifying table aliases, i.e.:

```
SELECT E.EQUIPMENTID, E.EQUIPMENTDESCRIPTION
From EQUIPMENT E
left outer join EQUIPMENT_CHECKOUT EC
on E.EQUIPMENTID = EC.EQUIPMENTID
WHERE EC.EQUIPMENTID is null
```

BTW: in Apex, you can try SQL statements in the SQL Commands window (in SQL Workshop) which usually gives better syntax error info.